# clustering key ordered by

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

In Cassandra, if I have the table below to store the students with scores. Partition key is the class_uuid and score is the clustering key. Put the potential hotspot issue aside, the wide row is to store all the students in the class sorted by score DESC.

```
CREATE TABLE class_students(
  class_uuid uuid,
  score double,
  student_uuid uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (class_uuid,score,student_uuid)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC);
;
```

My question is when there are two students with the same score, how does cassandra sort and save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One think to know is the clustering ordering is applied is the same partition key. In your exemple, students will be ordered by score in descending order with the same class_uuid. So tow student with same score in differents class will be order differentily.

However, if two students has the same score in the same class, the order is the insert order.